# Reference to a div without IDs

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with addEvent(or something else I don't know). This is my code.
HTML :

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:30px;width:30px;" ></div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;height:30px;width:30px;" ></div>
```

JS :

```
function addEvent(elm,ev,fun)//Cross-browser addEvent
{
    if(elm.addEventListener)elm.addEventListener(ev,fun,false);
    else if(elm.attachEvent)
    {
        var r=elm.attachEvent("on"+ev,fun);
        return r;
    }
}

function myFun(x)
{
    alert(x.style.backgroundColor);
}

var allDiv=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
myFun(allDiv[0]);//Here it works
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++) {
      //But not here when you click the div
      addEvent(allDiv[i],
               "click",function(){
                          myFun(allDiv[i])
                       });
}
```

I want that the alert works but without using IDs and without puting an inline onclick. Is it possible ?

http://jsfiddle.net/G9gBS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fall into a common trap when using closures in JavaScript. I is closed over but changes on all click functions are calling myFunc with `allDiv[allDiv.length -1]` you can use a self executing function to get around this

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++) {
          addEvent(allDiv[i],
                   "click",(function(j) {
                              return function(){
                                       myFun(allDiv[j])
                                     }
                            }(i)));
}
```

this no longer closes over i (i is never referenced in the function assigned to the click event).

in this particualr case however you can simply pass this. An event handler is called in the context of the element firing the event so you can do

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++) {
              addEvent(allDiv[i],
                       "click",function(){myFun(this)});
}
```

or even shorter using jQuery

```
var myFun function(x)
{
    alert(x.style.backgroundColor);
}

$("div").click(myFun);
```

Comment: And if I want to access to i onclick, what do I pass as parameter ?

Comment: @user1365010 in the first example I provided you use j where you would otherwise have used i

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling it as `allDiv[i]`, pass in `this` to the callback function.  At the time the onclick callback is called, `i` is out of scope and can't be resolved by `allDiv[i]`.  The callback is called in context of the calling `<div>`, referenced by `this`.

```
for(var i=0; i<allDiv.length; i++) {
      addEvent(allDiv[i], "click", function() {
         // allDiv[i] is out of scope in the callback.  Use this instead.
         myFun(this);
      });
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/G9gBS/2/)

Comment: @user1365010 Ok, found the real problem.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't understand why. this and allDiv[i] should be the same!

Comment: @user1365010 See the note I added above.  The `i`  index is out of scope at the time the callback gets called, and the callback function gets called in context of the calling div, `this`.

Comment: @user1365010 i is __not__ out of scope it's closed over (see my answer). The value of i at the time the callback is executed is therfor used. If the call back was executed after say half of the iterations then the value of i would be allDiv.length/2. However the callbacks aren't executed until i reaches it's final value and since it's the same variable (i) in each callback they all have the same value. That's by design when using closures in JS

Comment: And if I want to access to i onclick, what do I pass as parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++)addEvent(allDiv[i],"click",function(){myFun(allDiv[i])});
```

to

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++)addEvent(allDiv[i],"click",function(){myFun(this)});
```

> And if I want to access to i onclick, what do I pass as parameter?

like that, is one way (another would be to use a bind):

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++){
    var bob = i;
    addEvent(allDiv[i],"click",function(){
                               alert(bob);
                               myFun(this,bob);
    });
}
```

Comment: And if I want to access to i onclick, what do I pass as parameter ?